# Android service that detects if any app is opened by the user and starts timer in the background

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service

App which starts a service which keeps running in background till the user wishes to terminate. How to detect if any other app is opened or closed? I want to start a unique timer for different apps. And finally store all the logs. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Simply get current running task using ActivityManager

```
ActivityManager mActivityManager= (ActivityManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20)
{
   String mPackageName = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0).processName;
}
else
{
   String mpackageName = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
}
```

And you can also detect an app processs change's [**using this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39789643/3496570)
Also See [this Example](http://androidexample.com/Check_Current_Running_Activity_%7C_Task_%7C_Application_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=111&aaid=133)

Comment: I'm getting a error " cannot resolve symbol mContext"

Comment: But it returns all the apps that are currently running. How do I get the app which is "open" or currently being used by the user.

Comment: get(0) is returning current app running

Comment: `getRunningAppProcesses` returns the unordered list so you cannot get any assumptions about its first element, the docs say: `Returns a list of RunningAppProcessInfo records, or null if there are no running processes (it will not return an empty list). This list ordering is not specified.`

Comment: getRunningTasks(1).get(0) will do what you need. May be this help http://stackoverflow.com/a/28066580/3496570